# PowerBI running Total formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset OvertimeHours with EMPLID, checkdate and NumberOfHours (and other fields).  I need a running total NumberOfHours for each employee by checkdate.  I tried using the Quick Measure option but that only allows for a single column and I have two.  I do not want the measure to recalculate when filters are applied.  Ultimately what I am trying to do is identify the records for the first 6 hours of overtime worked on each check so that they can get a category of OCB and all overtime over the first 6 hours is OTP and it does not have to be exact (as demonstrated in the output below).  I have only been working with Power BI for about a month and this is a pretty complex (for me) formula to figure out...

```
EMPLID        CheckDate   WkDate   NumberOfHours   RunningTotal     Category
124             1/1/19    12/20/18    5               5             OCB
124             1/1/19    12/21/18    9               14            OTP
125             1/1/19    12/20/18    3               3             OCB
125             1/1/19    12/20/18    2               5             OCB
125             1/1/19    12/22/18    2               7             OTP
124             1/15/19   1/8/19      3               3             OCB
```

*Edited to add the WkDate.

Edit:
I have tweaked my query so that I have the running total and a sequential counter now:
[image]

Using the first 12 records, I am looking to get the following results:

[image]

I can either do it in a query if that is the easiest way or if there is a way to use DAX in PowerBI with this dataset now that I have the sequential piece, I can do that too.

Comment: There is a problem with your data - it does not contain any fields that define accumulation order. For example, for EMPLID=125, how do I know which number of hours must be first, second, third? layout by itself can't determine that. You need a column that, if sorted by, will arrange records in a proper sequence (i.e, a date-time stamp would work).

Comment: Ok I have another field, CalendarDate that is the date worked but there can be mutliple entries for the same date.

Comment: That won't help. You need either add "Time" field, or create a sequential index.

Comment: Ok, how do I add the sequential index?  Is that the 'Add index' function inside PBI, right?

Comment: It depends on what's available to you in your source data. If your source is a database, you might have record ID or record timestamp, and you can just add them to the table. Or, if your source is Excel, use row number. If none of that, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Actually, I do have a unique ID field already in the dataset, which it looks like is what the Add Index column does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it in the query:

```
select  r.CheckDate, 
        r.EMPLID, 
        case 
            when PayrollRunningOTHours <= 6 
                then PayrollRunningOTHours 
            else 6 
        end as OCBHours, 
        case 
            when PayRollRunningOTHours > 6 
                then PayRollRunningOTHours - 6 
        end as OTPHours 
from    #rollingtotal r
inner   
join    lastone l 
        on r.CheckDate = l.CheckDate 
        and r.EMPLID = l.EMPLID 
        and r.OTCounter = l.lastRec
order   by r.emplid, 
        r.CheckDate, 
        r.OTCounter
```